# Why isn't my code not looping with the Y/N condition, correctly?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Why isn't my code not looping with the Y/N condition, correctly?

Write a Python program to do the following:

**(a)** Ask the user to enter as many integers from 1 to 10 as he/she wants. Store the integers entered by the user in a list.  Every time after the user has entered an integer, use a yes/no type question to ask whether he/she wants to enter another one.
**(b)** Display the list.
**(c)** Calculate and display the average of the integers in the list.
**(d)** If the average is higher than 7, subtract 1 from every number in the list.  Display the modified list.

```
person = []
integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
person.append(integer_pushed)
again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")


while integer_pushed < 0 or integer_pushed > 10:
    print('You must type in an integer between 0 and 10')
    integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
    person.append(integer_pushed)
    again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")

while again == "y":
    integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
    person.append(integer_pushed)
    again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")
```

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you coded it to do. What output is differing from what you expect to see?

Comment: Why are you using `float` to get an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7 `input()` attempts to evaluates the input as a Python expression. You  want to use `raw_input()` instead.

In Python3, `input()` has the desired behavior.